# on key event executing multiple times android

Tags: android, dialog

I Am Showing Dialog in a Activity in my application.When I Detecting On Key event in a dialog it is executing multiple times.i have to go back to previous activity without dismiss dialog.can anyone have idea about it?

```
 @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                             KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && IsClicked==false) {

                if (GlobalApp.activity != null) {

                    Log.i("Activity",""+GlobalApp.activity);
                    IsClicked=true;

                    GlobalApp.activity.onBackPressed();

                    dialog_Footer.dismiss();
                }

            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: show your current code

Comment: what is executing multiple times ?

Comment: this method is executing multiple times

Comment: show your `onBackPressed` button method and try to debug why it is being called multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called twice, once for pressing the key, and the second time for releasing it. Try this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                         KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && IsClicked==false) {

            if (GlobalApp.activity != null) {

                Log.i("Activity",""+GlobalApp.activity);
                IsClicked=true;

                GlobalApp.activity.onBackPressed();

                dialog_Footer.dismiss();
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```